# PHP: Is FILTER_VALIDATE_URL safe to validate URLs?

Tags: php, security, validation, filter-var

I am using this to validate URLs:

```
if(!filter_var($website, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
// invalid url
} else 
   //url valid
```

Is this safe?
After reading this: http://www.d-mueller.de/blog/why-url-validation-with-filter_var-might-not-be-a-good-idea/ I am afraid not.

So is the provided solution safe?:

```
function validate_url($url)
{
    $url = trim($url);

    return ((strpos($url, "http://") === 0 || strpos($url, "https://") === 0) &&
            filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL, FILTER_FLAG_SCHEME_REQUIRED | FILTER_FLAG_HOST_REQUIRED) !== false);
}
```

Comment: Things like cross-site-scripting, SQL injetcion (even though I am using PDO) etc.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation does not state this, but the return value is a sanitised copy of the URL.

I.e.

```
<?php
echo filter_var('http://example.com/exploit.html?<script>alert(1);</script>', FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);
//http://example.com/exploit.html?
```

So if you work with the return value of the `filter_var()`, you are safer than working with the URL supplied to `filter_var()`.